# Method of Undetermined Coefficients vs. Modification Rule?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving 2nd order ODE's is the modification rule the same method as Undetermined Coefficients?

Comment: The medication rule?

Comment: Why would someone upvote this: Do they know what the "medication rule" is??

Comment: @lulu Sorry spelling error,  modification rule!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Fixed the spelling error sorry

Comment: Too bad!  I liked the idea of a medication rule.  I hadn't heard of the modification rule either but google has, see [this](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math4490/fall2009/reviewode.pdf).  It is not exactly the same as Undetermined Coefficients.  Rather, it applies in the case where the form you expect to solve an inhomogeneous equation happens to solve the homogeneous case.  In such a case it directs you to try to multiply by powers of $x$.

Comment: @lulu lol, it's fine to use the Undetermined Coefficients method to solve any non-homogeneous ODE correct? I mean, it's math right we could solve it in any way we'd like?

Comment: Of course.  The Modification Rule just comes in handy when the form you guess happens to not work because of "accidental" cancellations.  In such a case, it points you toward a way to modify your guess.  Take $y''-2y'+y=e^x$ for example.  a natural guess would be $y_p=e^x$ but that solves the homogeneous equation.  In this case you need $y_p=Ax^2e^x$.

Comment: Honestly, since I have an exam in about 2 hours and used to the Undetermined Coefficients method, and worked well with a lot of problems I'll stick to that, im worried if I try the mod. method I'll confused myself right now, thanks!